# Visual Studio MVC template creation issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to create a custom ASP.NET MVC4 template.  I start from the Basic MVC4 template, make my modifications, and then use the "Export Template" wizard to create the template zip file.  Right now (almost) everything is working smoothly.  When I use the template to create a new MVC application, it recreates all of my settings the way I want them except one.  For some reason, it changes the project properties for my web application to have a Start Action of "Current Page" instead of "Specific Page" (like it was in the original template and like it is in my template).  This setting is in the project properties under the Web tab.  Here is what it is set to in my template application (before I generate the actual template zip file):

[image: Correct Settings]

And here is what it is like when I create a new project using that template:

[image: Incorrect Settings]

How do I modify my template to set this setting properly (or more accurately, how do I force it to remember what I set initially)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: answer revised due to misunderstanding of both original request and behavior of previously proposed solution.

To set the Start Action of a custom MVC project template, you'll need to create a dll with a class that implements the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard` interface.  To use the wizard dll, you'll either need to copy it to Visual Studio's probing path, which is (VS2010 Install Dir)\Common7\IDE, (VS2010 Install Dir)\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, or (VS2010 Install Dir)\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.  If you don't put the compiled dll in one of those directories, you'll need to strong name and sign the dll and add it to the GAC and get the publickeytoken of the dll and add it to the Assembly element in the vstemplate file.

In testing the following code I copied the dll to (VS2010 Install Dir)\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, so the dll is not signed.

Wizard code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard;

namespace WarrenG.StartAction {
    public class Wizard : IWizard {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();


        public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
                               WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) {
            if (replacementsDictionary.ContainsKey("$wizarddata$")) {
                string xml = replacementsDictionary["$wizarddata$"];
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes) {
                    data.Add(node.Name, node.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath) {
            return true;
        }

        public void RunFinished() {
        }

        public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem) {
        }

        public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem) {
        }

        public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project) {
            if (data.ContainsKey("WebApplication.DebugStartAction")) {
                project.Properties.Item("WebApplication.DebugStartAction").Value =
                    data["WebApplication.DebugStartAction"];
            } else {
                project.Properties.Item("WebApplication.DebugStartAction").Value = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add wizard specific elements to vstemplate file of custom MVC project template

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateContent>
    <!-- various template content -->
  </TemplateContent>
  <!-- add the following -->
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>WarrenG.StartAction, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>WarrenG.StartAction.Wizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <WebApplication.DebugStartAction>1</WebApplication.DebugStartAction>
  </WizardData>
</VSTemplate>
```

The start actions on the project page appear to be numbers 0 through 4, following their display order. A value of 1 corresponds with Specific Page.

Comment: This answer looks like it is on the right track, but I cannot get it to work.  I did the modifications to the .user file and the template file and I updated the zip file appropriately.  However, it did not change the outcome (yes, I used the new template).  I then tried using the $projectname$ variable instead since that is how VS names the file normally - no go.  Is there an order to these lines I need to be aware of?  I put it right below the web.config entry.

Comment: I moved the new ProjectItem line to the end of the vstemplate file, but still nested in the Project tag, and I still get the correct output when generating a new project, so I don't think line order is important.

Comment: When you create a new project from the template, does the csproj.user file get created?

Comment: Yes, the csproj.user file gets created but it has the wrong information in it.  It looks like it is either ignoring my file or it is overwriting it.

Comment: Sounds like VS2010 is still reading the original template zip.  Double check that you're editing the correct zip file.  At the risk of telling you stuff you already know, if you set VS2010 to automatically import the new template in the template wizard, it will create two template zip files, one in %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio\My Exported Templates and the other in %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio\Templates\ProjectTemplates.  VS2010 will open an explorer window on My Exported Templates, but it creates new projects based on the zip file in ProjectTemplates.

Comment: Thanks for double-checking (it never hurts) but I've verified that it is using the new zip file (I made other cosmetic changes to ensure I'm using the newest one).

Comment: In the vstemplate file, is the ProjectItem entry nested in any of the Folder tags?  If it is, but the csproj.user file is not in the corresponding folder in the zip file, the csproj.user file will not get copied and VS2010 won't give you any notification about it.  In my vstemplate file, the path to the ProjectItem entry is <VSTemplate><TemplateContent><Project><ProjectItem>

Comment: It is not nested in a folder.  I put it at the same folder-level as the base web.config file.  My path to the ProjectItem is the same as yours.  I have also tried to play with the naming of the file (safeprojectname, projectname, <the actual name>, etc.) with no luck.

Comment: I uploaded to filedropper a template that works on my machine.  You can get it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/mycustommvcapptemplate).  Try using it to create a new project and see if the csproj.user file comes through correctly.  If not, maybe there's something else in your VS2010 that's overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I'm not yet able to download that file (firewall restrictions).  I'll be able to download it tonight though.  I'll try it out as soon as I can.  In the meantime, I'm going to award you the points for the effort.

Comment: Even when I'm not behind the firewall I can't get that template to download.  Filedropper just goes to the main page when I click the link.

Comment: So much for filedropper's assertion that they won't delete files for 30 days.  Here is a [link](http://db.tt/4yMbRTSE) to the file on my dropbox account.

Comment: I tried this template out on my home computer and it didn't work properly.  The option is defaulted to "Current Page".

Comment: I finally realized that I misread your question and have had the desired setting and the actual setting reversed.  After figuring that out, I then realized that my original solution wasn't working at all, VS2010 was overwriting the csproj.user file, but I thought the end result was correct due to my initial misunderstanding.  I've revised my answer with a (more thoroughly tested) code based approach that sets the start action correctly.  My apologies for the wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, or fortunately, depending on the side of the coin you're on...

Like the "Startup Project" setting, that setting is NOT part of the project file or the template file that's generated. It is stored in the "SUO" or Solution User Options, file. The SUO is not included by the template generator.

Some background on the SUO file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I understand that this is a user setting.  However, I want to set it initially just like the standard MVC templates do.  When I add a standard MVC template, the setting is set properly for how a MVC application works.  When I take that same template and create a new one based upon it, the resulting template does not set this setting properly.  That is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I don't believe it's possible... that information is not captured in the information saved by the `Export Template...` functionality. The SUO format, where the setting is stored, is an undocumented binary format.

Comment: I understand but what I am saying is that the standard templates do it so it must be possible.

Comment: I just looked through the built-in templates in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033` - there's nothing there that I can see that sets it.